# Connect to 2 instances of MySQL with no password interaction using command line

Tags: mysql, ssh

I would like to connect to mysql database without interaction for the password (I need for using it during a batch script). I'm using this script, but before start the connection I must insert the password.

```
mysql -u username@databasename -p "Password" -h hostnamedatabase -P 3344
```

I have tried this other approach but I have no success

```
mysql -u username@databasename -pPassword -h hostnamedatabase -P 3344
```

Is there a way to enter the password directly without typing it in?

Answer (score 1):

## New answer

OP is on command line on a remote server (using SSH). From there, `mysql` needs to be used password-less - so to speak - to create user on INSTANCE1 and INSTANCE2.

That's doable also. You'd use `--defaults-group-suffix` switch.

**~/.my.cnf**

Let's start with creating a file called .my.cnf in your home directory (aka ~/.my.cnf). Put this in it.

```
[client1]
user=INSTANCE1-USERNAME
password=INSTANCE1-PASSWORD
database=INSTANCE1-DATABASE (this could be mysql)
host=INSTANCE1-HOSTNAME-OR-IP

[client2]
user=INSTANCE2-USERNAME
password=INSTANCE2-PASSWORD
database=INSTANCE2-DATABASE (this could be mysql)
host=INSTANCE2-HOSTNAME-OR-IP
```

Save the file. Do `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf` to ensure only your username and root/root-like user can see it.

Now, type this to get to first server:

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=1
```

Then, use this to get to the second server:

```
mysql --defaults-group-suffix=2
```

**Explanation**

Typically ~/.my.cnf will have the following block

```
[client]
user=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
database=DATABASE (this could be mysql)
host=localhost (or whatever hostname/IP)
```

That allows you to just type `mysql` and log on. MySQL looks for credentials, host, port etc. in `~/.my.cnf`. If it gets that info, it'll use it to log in to MySQL. Cool. Easy enough.

`--defaults-group-suffix=2` tells MySQL to look into `~/.my.cnf` but not read the `[client]` block but instead read the `[client2]` block for credentials/information.

Similarly `--defaults-group-suffix=1` tells MySQL to look into `~/.my.cnf` and read the `[client1]` block for credentials/information.

That way, you can have credentials for multiple servers or databases within a single server and log on to MySQL without having to prompt/provide credentials through command line.

You can use this tool with scripts as long as the ~/.my.cnf file is in the username that is running those scripts.

**Documentation**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-file-options.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html#option-file-syntax

## Another method using `--login-path`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html. It shows you can log on to mysql using `--login-path` switch. Since the above method will work well for you, I am just adding this as a reference.

## Old answer

You can actually do that. Assuming you are on Linux, create a `.my.cnf` file under your home directory. Type this in it:

```
[client]
user=username
password=yourpass
```

Then, you can do `mysql -h host -P 3344 -D databasename`

See documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Also make sure that this file is adequately protected (do `chmod 600 ~/.my.cnf`).

Comment: But If I need to execute a connection for two different kind of database?

Comment: 2 different servers or 2 different databases on the same server @DavidInTheIn?

Comment: In my current computer there is no database. I would connect to differents database remotely and execute differente mysql script for different database. Thanks

Comment: Perfect. That helps. Do you connect to the other database using SSH through a terminal (command line)?

Comment: yes, one script to create a user in a database A, another script to create a user in database B

Comment: @DavidInTheIn I've provided you a new answer that should work well for your use case.